# reading from a file and writing to a file skipping certain lines in python

Tags: python

A small part of a bigger code problem I am working on: I am reading the content from a file: **glmfile.glm**. I am trying to write each line from **glmfile.glm** to another file: **combined.glm** skipping lines meeting certain criteria.

```
glmfile=open("glmfile.glm",'r').readlines()
combined=open("combined.glm",'w')
```

The content of **glmfile.glm** looks like this:

```
...
#other objects
object node {
    name SPU123-389-3066753-3_breaker_rec_recnode;
    phases ABC;
    nominal_voltage 7621.024;
}

object node {
    name SPU123-416-25308_recnode;
    phases ABC;
    nominal_voltage 7621.024;
}
object node {
    name SPU123-403-492320;
    groupid from_db;
    phases CN;
    nominal_voltage 7621.024;
}

object node {
    name SPU123-392-97334;
    groupid from_db;
    phases ABCN;
    nominal_voltage 7621.024;
}

object node {
    name SPU123-391-348982;
    groupid from_db;
    phases AN;
    nominal_voltage 7621.024;
}

object node {
    name SPU123-391-542649;
    groupid from_db;
    phases AN;
    nominal_voltage 7621.024;
}
#few more node objects and other objects
...
```

Now, I formed an array of `node_names` that looks like this:

```
node_names=['389-3066753','403-492320','392-97334','391-348982']
```

I am comparing the name of **glmfile** with the elements in the array to see if the **object node name** is listed in the array `node_names`:

```
for h,aaline in enumerate(glmfile):
    if aaline.startswith('object node {') and ('SWING' not in glmfile[h+3]):
        if glmfile[h+1][13:-2].strip() in node_names:
            #DO NOT WRITE THAT ENTIRE OBJECT NODE SECTION to 'combined'
            #I am able to skip just that line 'glmfile[h]' but how to NOT   
            #write out the entire object node i.e., glmfile[h:h+6]?
            print glmfile[h:h+6]
        else:
            combined.writelines([glmfile[h:h+6]])
```

NOTE: The problem I am struggling with is in the above code snippet in `if case` comment.

Comment: Does enumerate pull a file line by line? I was under the impression it broke down everything into a tuple.

Comment: @EricThomas enumerating a file object returns `[(line_number, line_as_str), ...]`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is you're trying to do. Can you write it in English? I understand that you're trying to read from `glmfile` and write to `combined` if and only if some conditions are matched (or aren't matched?) but can you tell us precisely what those conditions are?

Comment: @AdamSmith if  the numeric portion of **name** of **object node** is in array, I DON'T want to write out that object (i.e., object node { ... }) else: write everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk broad terms first, and specify from there.

You have objects that look like:

```
object node {
    name NAME_VAL;
    phases PHASES_VAL;
    nominal_voltage VOLTAGE_VAL;
}
```

You're trying to write from one file full of these objects to another blank file, only taking such objects that

```
'SWING' in PHASES_VAL and NAME_VAL in [some list of nodes].
```

Let's do this then:

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None)
    '''from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html'''
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

with open('path/to/infile.txt') as inf, \
        open('path/to/outfile.txt', 'w') as outf:
    objects_in = grouper(inf, 6) # 5 lines of the object plus a newline
    for obj in objects_in:
        obj = list(obj) # let's look at them all at once
        NAME_VAL = obj[1].strip().split()[1]
        PHASES_VAL = obj[2].strip().split()[1]
        VOLTAGE_VAL = obj[3].strip().split()[1]
        if 'SWING' in PHASES_VAL and \
                NAME_VAL in some_list_of_nodes:
            outf.writelines(obj)
```

That said, if this was something you're going to be doing over and over again, it's probably better to write a parser for this.

```
# node.py

class Node(dict):
    '''simply inheriting from dict will handle almost everything,
    but we will have to give it a classmethod to build from string'''

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s):
        kwargs = {}
        reading = False
        for line in s.splitlines():
            if "}" in line:
                return cls.__init__(**kwargs)
            if reading:
                key,val = line.strip().split()
                kwargs[key]=val
            if "{" in line:
                reading = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "object node {\n" + \
                "\n".join("    {} {}".format(item)\
                          for item in self.items()) + "\n}"
```

```
# parser.py

from node import Node

def parse(f):
    tokens = []
    token = []
    parsing = False
    for line in inf:
        if line.startswith('object node {'):
            parsing = True
        if parsing:
            token.append(line.strip())
        if line.strip() == "}":
            parsing = False
            obj = Node("\n".join(token))
            tokens.append[obj]
            token = []
    return tokens
```

```
# yourfile.py

import parser

with open('path/to/infile.txt') as infile, \
        open('path/to/outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for obj in parser.parse(infile):
        if obj['name'] in some_node_names_list and \
               'SWING' in obj['phases']:
            outfile.write(str(obj))
```

Comment: I tried the second approach but I am getting **'module' object has no attribute 'parse'** error. The first approach errored with **'module' object has no attribute 'zip_longest'**

Comment: @NikhilGupta If you're on Python2, use `izip_longest` instead of `zip_longest`

Comment: the first approach is doing something else actually. I am still not able to get your second approach to compile.

Comment: @NikhilGupta If both `node.py` and `parser.py` are in your `PYTHONPATH`, it should work fine. That said: I haven't tested it at all so I could be completely wrong!! The error you said it was throwing definitely SHOULDN'T happen if they're all on your `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 0):

how about using an extra index and the modulo operator:

```
a%b
```

for example:

```
idx = 6
for h,aaline in enumerate(glmfile):
if aaline.startswith('object node {') and ('SWING' not in glmfile[h+3]):
    if glmfile[h+1][13:-2].strip() in node_names or idx%6!=0:
        idx = idx+1
        print glmfile[h:h+6]
        pass
    else:
        combined.writelines([glmfile[h:h+6]])
```